# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412 () when using emailjs in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, gmail, vite

I am trying to integrate emailjs into my React app to send emails. However, I am getting an error in the console that says:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412 ()"

when I try to send an email. I have checked the server logs and there are no errors there.

Here's the code I am using:

```js
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser"
// Function to handle sending the email
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)

    emailjs
      .send(
        EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,
        EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID,
        {
          from_name: form.name,
          to_name: "Umair ul islam",
          from_email: form.email,
          to_email: "umairulislam09@gmail.com",
          message: form.message,
        },
        EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY
      )
      .then(
        () => {
          setLoading(false)
          alert("Thank you. I will get back to you as soon as possible.")

          setForm({
            name: "",
            email: "",
            message: "",
          })
        },
        (error) => {
          setLoading(false)
          console.error(error)

          alert("something went wrong. Please try again.")
        }
      )
  }
```

I have checked the emailjs documentation and I am using the correct service ID, template ID, and user ID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code seems fine, probably need to check keys.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem (error 412) when I used uppercase letters in the email address etc. When I changed to lowercase the problem went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).